# Horizon/RethinkDB api

Tags: rethinkdb, horizon

So I have one error and two questions about Horizon. (http://horizon.io/docs/)
I have a simple table and 1 record inside, this is the row:

```
id: "o34242-43251-462...",
user_id: "3lw5-6232s2...",
other_id: "531h51-51351..."
```

When I run **hz serve** I'm getting this error:

**Unexpected index name (invalid field): "hz_[["user_id"],[["other_id","0"]]]"**.

Okay, okay, invalid field... But I didn't find any informations about "valid" fields. Anybody knows the answer?  What can I do?

My questions:

1. How to run Horizon "forever" on ubuntu? Now I'm using just hz serve and "&",
2. If I have few queries, for example:

   ```
   let table = this.horizon('firstTable');
   let table2 = this.horizon('secondTable');

       table.find(someId).fetch().subscribe((item) => {
          //and then I want to run other query, e.g: 
          table2.find(item.id).fetch().subscribe((value) => {
          //and here again run other query... <-- how to avoid this?
          });
       });
   ```

   How to e.g return a value from horizon's query, and then use this value inside other query? I don't want to write it all in one function...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is better way, how to achieve this, checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40037527/1432356

Comment: post this as an answer, then I'll mark it as a best ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since 'fetch' returns an RxJS observable, and it yield one result only, you can use 'toPromise' to consume it in a convenient fashion.

```
let table = this.horizon('firstTable');
let table2 = this.horizon('secondTable');

let item1 = await table.find(someId).fetch().toPromise();
let item2 = await table2.find(item1.id).fetch().toPromise();
```

Or without ES7 await, just using Promise.then:

```
table.find(someId).fetch().toPromise().then((item1) => {
    table2.find(item1.id).fetch().toPromise().then((item2) => {
      // take over the world from here
    });
});
```